# sort list of list  based on size of the subList?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, java-6

I have a List of List. I want to sort the Super List depends on the sub list size. The Lists are dynamic.
The List type is `<ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap>>>` Eg.

```
[ [{key1=value1,key2=value2}],[],[{key1=value1}],[{key1=value1},{key2=value2},{key3=value3}]  ]
```

After The sorting it should display

```
[[{key1=value1},{key2=value2},{key3=value3}], [{key1=value1,key2=value2}],[{key1=value1}],[]  ]
```

Can you help how to sort this?

Thanks in advance.
Laxman chowdary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***EDITED*** :

If you want to sort a List of List of Map ordered by List of Map size you can do this.

Note that you can change the order of parameters (`o1` and `o2`) in `Integer.valueOf(o1.size()).compareTo(o2.size())` to sort in the decreasing order.

```
public static <T> List<? extends List<T>> sortListByValue(List<? extends List<T>> list) {

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<List<T>>() {


        @Override
        public int compare(List<T> o1, List<T> o2) {
            //return Integer.compare(o1.size(), o2.size()); //JDK7 

            //Use this if you're using a version prior to 1.7.
            return Integer.valueOf(o1.size()).compareTo(o2.size());
        }
    });

    return list;
}   


public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Map<String,String>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(new HashMap<String, String>(){{ put("1", "a"); put("2", "b");}});
    list1.add(new HashMap<String, String>(){{ put("1", "a"); put("2", "b"); put("3", "c");}});
    list1.add(new HashMap<String, String>(){{ put("1", "a"); }});

    ArrayList<Map<String,String>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add(new HashMap<String, String>(){{ put("1", "a"); put("2", "b");}});
    list2.add(new HashMap<String, String>(){{ put("1", "a"); put("2", "b"); put("3", "c");}});

    ArrayList<Map<String,String>> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
    list3.add(new HashMap<String, String>(){{ put("1", "a"); put("2", "b");}});

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String,String>>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(list1);
    list.add(list2);
    list.add(list3);
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(sortListByValue(list));
}
```

Comment: Hi alain, the following error coming..The method compare(int, int) is undefined for the type Integer.. how to resolve it?

Comment: @Laxmanchowdary Sorry it's only for JDK7 use this instead : `return Integer.valueOf(o1.size()).compareTo(o2.size());`

Comment: @Laxmanchowdary Reading your update you 're using `<ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap>>>` so it's 3 level of list, are you sure you need so much lists?? Because reading your exemples it's just `ArrayList<HashMap>`

Comment: What you have provided the code is for sorting Map values in a list.. But my requirement is to sort the list based on the sub list size in descending order...

Comment: @Laxmanchowdary Ok, I see so you have just one pair in your HashMap? The size of HashMap doesn't count, it's only the size of the second list?

Answer (score 2):

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<List<? extends Map>>() {
        public int compare(List<? extends Map> list1, List<? extends Map> list2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(list1.size()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(list2.size()));
        }
    });
```

If you do not take care about generics that much you can simplify it such as:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<List>() {
            public int compare(List list1, List list2) {
                return Integer.valueOf(list1.size()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(list2.size()));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi Wojtek, it is throwing the following error.. The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<List>, new Comparator<List<String>>(){})

Comment: If you declared your list as `List<List>` only and not `List<List<String>>` the you might get rid of all "`<String>`" parts in my code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> sortBySublistSize(List<List<T>> superList) {
    Collections.sort(superList, new Comparator<List<T>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(List<T> o1, List<T> o2) {
            return Integer.compare(o1.size(), o2.size());
        }
    });

    return superList;
}
```

Comment: Hi Fabian, I'm using jdk6. Integer.compare(o1.size(), o2.size())  will not work in jdk6.. It is a feature of jdk7..

Comment: @Laxmanchowdary use `Integer.valueOf(o1.size()).compareTo(o2.size())` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use any normal sort algorithm but instead of basing on value just base on the length of the element instead.